# Create a button on custom object that opens a new Event linked to that custom object

Tags: custom-button, custom, urlhacking, url

I am trying to add a custom button to my custom object. On clicking the custom button, I want to open a new event which has the "related to" field prefilled with the custom object, and the "subject" field to be prefilled with "Review Meeting".

I have tried this:

```
https://na4.salesforce.com/00U/e?what_id={!customObj__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!customObj__c.Id}&RecordType=00h2000000OBSz6&ent=Event
```

But I seem to be missing something. As far as I understood from material I read online, it should be possible, but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Tia, 
lily

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to reference the html page element ids.

For example

- tsk5 = Subject
- tsk3_mlktp = the related to object type (006 is opportunity, etc)
- tsk3 = the related to display name
- tsk3_lkid = the related to linked id

https://na1.salesforce.com/00T/e?**tsk5**=TEST&**tsk3_mlktp**=006&**tsk3**=myOppy&**tsk3_lkid**=006800xx00qch4C&what_id=001800xx001Cr0vK&retURL=%2F0018xx0001Cr0vK

To discover these element ids use Firebug or similar to inspect element on the edit page for a new task:
[image]